# java.net.MalformedURLException in Java Selenium code

Tags: java, selenium, automation, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I tried to run simple Java Selenium code but am getting this error - can anyone help me to figure it out?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
stem.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();       
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
String Title = driver.getTitle();

//compare the actual title of the page with the expected one
if (Title.contentEquals("Google"))
{
System.out.println("Test Passed!");
}
else
{
System.out.println("Test Failed");
}
driver.close();
}
```

}

Comment: it means the **Url is invalid**. What's the URL ?

Comment: I've passed the link  as **driver.get("http://google.com");**

Comment: It seems you u wrote 'stem ' instead of 'System'

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using incorrect url in `get()` method. Try to use `get()` method like below:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

> URL must contains "http://" or "https://" to define its protocol.

Fix in your code, you can try below once inside `WebDriver Sampler` :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
   try{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/apache-jmet‌​er-
      3.1/bin/chromedri‌​ver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    String Title = driver.getTitle();
    if (Title.contentEquals("Google")){
      System.out.println("Test Passed!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Test Failed");
    } 
    driver.close();
  } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

}

Comment: @PrashanthNagendra, please post screenshot of WebDriver Sampler.

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDr . . . '' Token Parsing Error:

Comment: sir i tried with the exception handling code, it didnt worked

Comment: @PrashanthNagendra Please use this code. Note the double slash in the setProperty. Thanks!

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\pathto\\my\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://apache-jmeter-3.1//bin//chromedriver.exe");
```

As described in the javadoc for the System class:

> Sets the system property indicated by the specified key.
>
> First, if a security manager exists, its
>   SecurityManager.checkPermission method is called with a
>   PropertyPermission(key, "write") permission. This may result in a
>   SecurityException being thrown. If no exception is thrown, the
>   specified property is set to the given value.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> key - the name of the system property.   value - the value of the
>   system property.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the previous value of the system property, or null if it did not have
>   one. Throws:   SecurityException - if a security manager exists and
>   its checkPermission method doesn't allow setting of the specified
>   property.   NullPointerException - if key or value is null.
>   IllegalArgumentException - if key is empty.

Comment: please explain why

Comment: I don’t understand answer which does not have content to explain. I might flag this answer.